# Emulate curl request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, curl, pfx

I have to emulate curl request in nodejs:

```
curl -k POST https://example.com/ --cert mycert.pem:password
```

I already wrote some code, but it is not work similar:

```
request.post(
  {
    'url': 'https://example.com/',
    'agentOptions': {
      'pfx': fs.readFileSync('./mycert.pem'),
      'passphrase': 'password',
    }
  }
)
```

Getting "**Error: wrong tag**". But it works for curl.
I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: pretty sure `fs` is not a pem parser.

Comment: Why not? PEM - is just text file with list of certificates and private key in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is solution:

```
request.post(
  {
    'url': 'https://example.com/',
    'key': {
      'cert': fs.readFileSync('./mycert.pem'),
      'key': fs.readFileSync('./mycert.pem'),
      'passphrase': 'password',
    }
  }
)
```

Still wondering, how to use "pfx" option...

Answer (score 0):

does the following work?

```
const exec = require('child-process-promise').exec;
const cmd = 'curl -k POST https://example.com/ --cert mycert.pem:password';
exec(cmd).then(res => console.log(res.stdout)).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But is not proper solution. It should be done by nodejs tools to avoid OS incompatibility.